# ajax call checkbox internet explorer

Tags: php, ajax, forms, internet-explorer

I'm having this little problem with internet explorer and ajax. 
So first I used just php, and everything, worked, but because I don't want to reload the page, I use ajax.

So I have a form with a checkbox. When someone clicks on the checkbox, my ajaex is called and the input is changed in the db. In firefox there is no problem, but It doesn't work in internet explorer.

Here's a part of my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changefield($doss, $display){
    $.get("update.php",{dossier: $doss, CSQ_DISPLAY:$display});
    alert("test");
}
</script>


echo '<form id="'.$r ['BC_DOSSIER'].'" method="get" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="CSQ_DISPLAY" '.$checked .' onchange="changefield(\''.$r ['BC_DOSSIER'].'\',this.checked)">
</form>';
```

It seems that in explorer, I only get the alert when the checkbox was checked. (Problem because it first reads the db if it must be checked or not, so you can change it later).

Does someone know where I went wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for the answers.

Comment: The on* attributes aren't really used that much anymore because it means mingling javascript and HTML, something that libraries like jQuery were created to avoid in the first place.  You're better off giving the checkbox an ID (or class if you need the same code to work with several checkboxes on the same page) and attaching the click event handler with jQuery, especially as you're already using jQuery anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to define it like this, I hate using `onclick` in my HTML:

*edit* **FIXED** (registered to `change` instead of `click`)
*edit* Wrapped in `$(document).ready()`
*edit* Added a `click` event as well

```
<?php
  echo '<input class="ajax_check" id="check_'.htmlspecialchars($r['BC_DOSSIER']).'" type="checkbox" name="CSQ_DISPLAY" '.$checked .' />';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.ajax_check').click(function() {
      this.blur();
    });
    $('input.ajax_check').change(function() {
      var dossierId = this.id.slice(6);
      var isChecked = (this.checked) ? 1 : 0; // better to explicitly convert bool to int for HTTP requests
      $.get('update.php',{
        dossier: dossierId,
        CSQ_DISPLAY: isChecked
      });
      alert('test');
    });
  });
</script>
```

This will register that handler to all inputs with the className 'ajax_check', without leaving a function cluttering up the window object, and without messing up your HTML. Try it out and see if it fixes the problem - it may not as it does basically the same thing, but it's a better way of doing it IMHO. If you still have a problem, come back to me and we'll debug it.

Note that using this approach, it is important that the `<script>` is executed *after* the DOM is ready, so it should either be defined in the body after the checkbox or (better) wrapped inside `$(window).load()` or (best) `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but with your answer, it also wont work anymore in firefox.

Comment: Do you get any errors? And have you set the `id` and `class` attributes of the `<input>` correctly?

Comment: Hi, I don't get any error messages. In explorer it just won't go into the function.

Comment: Have you made sure that the `$('input.ajax_check').change()` is called after the DOM is available? You should probably call it in a `$(document).ready()` - see my edit in one minute.

Comment: I will try again: but meanwhile I did something different: I changed in my code the onchange to  onclick. Now at least it goes into the function, I get an alert, but it doesn't change the data into the db.

Comment: No it won't work in `click`, because this fires before the value of `checked` has been changed (in some browsers at least), and it also fires if you click on the box but don't change the value. Actually, I seem to remember that `onchange` doesn't fire in IE until the input loses focus. Try the edit above in a minute.

Comment: ok it worked, I did something very stupid. So in my upload.php I check for false or true, but you wrote 1 or 0. Of course I always got a false. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user993177 It is better to use 1/0 for booleans in HTTP requests, because in PHP you can evaluate them as a boolean and it will result in the right value. Checking for the strings 'false' and 'true' I don't like doing, because a) it relies on the browser sending one of those exact strings, and b) it is case sensitive (although this can be worked around).

Answer (score 0):

In your code fallback function value wont passed for IE.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CSQ_DISPLAY" '.$checked .' onchange="changefield(\''.$r ['BC_DOSSIER'].'\',this.checked)">
```

i.e) in above code onchange="changefield(\''.$r ['BC_DOSSIER'].'\',this.checked)"    this.checked will not work for IE, so you can pass as this and get the value in four function, this will work for all the browsers. e.g) like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CSQ_DISPLAY" '.$checked .' onchange="changefield(\''.$r ['BC_DOSSIER'].'\',this)">
```

and get the checked attribute inside the function.

I hope this will work.

Comment: With your answer, my problem still is the same. Everything works in firefox, but not in explorer. I used this in my ajax function: $display = $display.checked. but it seems he won't go in my function.

Comment: @user993177 can you put alert for $display after your code  $display = $display.checked if you get undefined , can you try with $display = $display.getAttribute('checked') ;